# C++ create a usable method in the child class

Tags: c++

This my base class

```
class Base {
protected:
    int number;
public:
    Base(int num);
    virtual void display() = 0;  
};
```

these two classes have inherited Base.

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived(int num);
    void display(){cout <<"hello";}
    void other();
};

class Derived2: public Base {
public:
    Derived(int num);
    void display(){cout <<"hello other";}
};
```

this class allows me to just instantiate my two classes Derived and Derived2

```
class Foo{
private:
    Base * toto[2];
public:
    Foo(){
     toto[0] = new Derived;
     toto[1] = new Derived2;
    }

    void doSomething();
}
```

and I want to do this

```
void Foo::doSomething(){
    toto[0]->other();
}
```

$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

last Question I create a new class inherited `Derived2` and `Base`

```
class Derived3: public Derived2, public Base {
public:
    Derived(int num);
    void display(){cout <<"hello";}
    void other();
};
```

now i want to do this

```
toto[0] = new Derived3

This my error message
```

Ambiguous conversion from derived class 'Derived3' to base class 'Base':
     class Derived3 -> class Base
     class Derived3 -> class Derived2 -> class Base

Assigning to 'Base *' from incompatible type 'Derived3 *'

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I want to call my method other in the Derived class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `toto[0]` is always going to point to `Derived` and `toto[1]` is always going to point to `Derived2`, you should probably do this:

```
class Foo{
private:
    Derived d1;
    Derived2 d2;
    Base * toto[2];
public:
    Foo(){
        toto[0] = &d1;
        toto[1] = &d2;
    }

    void doSomething() {
        d1.other();
    }
};
```

If you really have a *bona fide* need to create a situation where typing cannot be statically checked, then use `dynamic_cast`. But try to avoid that if possible. Don't treat C++ like a dynamically typed language.

```
Derived* dptr = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(toto[0]);
if (dptr) {
    dptr->other();
} else {
    throw std::logic_error("toto[0] should point to Derived");
}
```

Comment: @Darkness007 `Derived3` contains two copies of `Base`, that's why it's ambiguous: one because you derived from `Base` directly and one because you derived from `Derived2` which contains a `Base`. You probably don't want `Derived3` to inherit directly from `Base`. Also, in the future, please post a new question instead of adding more questions to an existing question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dinamic cast: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

```
void Foo::doSomething(){
    Derived* e =  dynamic_cast<Derived*>(toto[0]);

    if (e != nullptr) //Did cast work?
        e->other();
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to check that the cast succeded, i.e. that `e` is not `nullptr` BEFORE calling `e->other()`

Comment: @Christophe Edited. Thanks Christophe